# Formula for calculating length of half ellipse with triangle inside

Tags: geometry

I would like to calculate the length of half of an ellipse by using the angle ($\alpha$) of the constituent triangle and the length of the long diameter ($L$), as in the picture blow.[image]

I can't find anywhere such a formula. Is there anyone that can help me find a formula for $L_{elipse}$?

Comment: It's an elliptic integral.

Comment: Finding the ellipse axis is no big deal ($L$ and $L\tan\alpha$), but the length requires a special function. Efficient numerical evaluation can be doen by the arithmetico-geometric iterative method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference